# TabHost and PhoneGap

Tags: android, native, cordova, android-tabhost

I'm trying to add native tabs to my phonegap application on Android.
I have a way of doing it where each tab has it's own Activity and use loadUrl to load Phonegap in the view but it raises two problems.

1. I'm afraid the app is going to be
   awfully slow if I have 5 tabs each
   running Phonegap with some
   javascript.
2. If I go back to a tab,
       the last instance state has been
       saved, so if i clicked on a link
       from the tab, clicking back on the
       tab doesn't load back the main page.

I'm thinking about creating a layout main.xml with a custom linear layout and some callback buttons to call something like : super.loadUrl("javascript: goTo page rand;"); but I'm not sure this is the best way since I would have to rewrite the tabs functionality and design.

Thanks !

Comment: how to create tab in phonegap application on Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need the tabs to be native because of some architectural constraint? If not how about using a framework like Sencha Touch which provides tab UI controls? There's a demo in the kitchensink code:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/

The framework works pretty well from what I've seen inside of Phonegap.

Comment: It's not a necessity no, I'm using Jquery Mobile, which has the same Toolbar emulation, I might going back to that I think :)

Comment: I second this. Instead of running multiple instances of PhoneGap, use one, and do all of your tab/switching magic in HTML/CSS/JS - that's the point of PhoneGap!